# d3.js data.columns doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to recreate a simple example as seen here:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html

Here is a simple version of my code (note that the data has different labels but is structurally identical):

```js
  var data = [
{period:'t1', fmc1:+10, fmc2:9, fmc3:6, fmc4:5, fmc5:2},
{period:'t2', fmc1:+11, fmc2:8, fmc3:6, fmc4:4, fmc5:3},
{period:'t3', fmc1:+12, fmc2:10, fmc3:7, fmc4:5, fmc5:3},
  ];

  var groups = d3.map(data, function(d){return(d.period)}).keys()

  var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);

  var stackedData = d3.stack()
   .keys(subgroups)
   (data);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,80])
  .range([height,0]);

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(groups)
  .range([0,width])
  .padding([.2]);

  var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(subgroups)
  .range(["#003366","#366092","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#e7eef8","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#ffffcc","#f6d18b","#e4a733","#b29866","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#e7eef8","#b8cce4","#95b3d7","#4f81b9","#366092","#003366"]);

  graphGroup.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(stackedData)
  .enter().append("g")
.attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.key); })
.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.data.period); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]); })
  .attr("width",xScale.bandwidth())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I'm confronted with an error that reads:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined @ line 47.

That line is:

```
  var subgroups = data.columns.slice(1);
```

I confirmed in the console that `data.columns` is indeed, undefined. This begs the question as to what the author of the d3-graph-gallery is trying to do. I'm convinced there is an explanation, and the visual seems to work just fine on the website. Initial troubleshooting on my end didn't turn up much, doesn't seem to be a version issue.

### Question

If `data.columns.slice(1)` is a conventional approach to constructing a stacked bar chart (as the tutorial would lead one to believe) why isn't it working for me? I'm hoping there is a quick fix or something that can be tweaked easily so that I can follow the rest of the tutorial without diverging too much in terms of syntax and methodology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is an array. JavaScript arrays can be given properties, but it's not really considered good practice, because you're "sneaking" stuff into the object.

In this case, `data.columns` is set by the CSV reader, which you don't use here. The following is equivalent to the value of `data.columns`:

```
Object.keys(data[0])
```